# Sybase - Concatenate Two Integer Variable Being Date Format

Tags: sql, date, integer, concatenation, sybase

I try to concatenate "Year" and "Month" variables.These variables are kept being integer type. However, "Year" variable holds its

```
records ->"2015","2016"
```

and "Month" variable holds its

```
records->"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12".
```

I would like to see my desired variable like `->"201501","201502"` etc. How can I reach my desired output?

Here is my script->

```
Select CONVERT(DATE,TRIM(CONVERT(CHAR(4),YEAR)||(Case When MONTH<10 Then '0' || Convert(Char(2),MONTH) Else Convert(Char(2),MONTH) End ))) Into #New_Table1
From Table1
```

Answer (score 0):

Among the many ways to solve this: chane your first 'CHAR(2)' to 'CHAR(1)'